# Azure devops XamarinAndroid build task doesn't add proguard.map/mapping.txt into generated .aab file

Tags: xamarin, azure-devops

I am trying to incorporate Xamarin debugging symbols into an .aab generated by a DevOps CI task "XamarinAndroid@1". Building an Archive in Visual Studio puts the proguard.map file into the .aab, but it doesn't work when built in Azure DevOps CI.

I **think** I have tracked the problem down via logs: when VisualStudio calls "bundletool.jar" it passes an extra parameter

> -metadata-file=com.android.tools.build.obfuscation/proguard.map:bin\Release\mapping.txt

But the bundletool.jar call in CI doesn't have the extra -metadata-file parameter.

How can I force the parameter to show up when bundletool.jar is called in CI?

I have tried passing an extra parameter to MSBuild

> /p:AndroidCreateProguardMappingFile=True

as per [github documentation here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/commit/2994604c15fa70f8975c446e502218bc81f8ecf2) (even though I am using R8 and "True" is the default).

I'm stuck and would appreciate any tips!

Comment: I would like to ask if you are using Android 9.2 or above，because the string property for extra parameter calls may be added in Xamarin.Android 9.2.

Comment: The CI logs say: 
_ResolveXamarinAndroidTools:
   Found Xamarin.Android 12.0.0.3
But I am not used to fiddling with these kinds of things; maybe I will tinker and see what I can find there?

Comment: The CI is on macos-latest (which has Xamarin.Android 12.0) and I found that the Windows agents are running Xamarin.Android 12.3. The feature I am looking for appears to be in 12.3:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/12/12.3

Comment: You may upgrade under the next try, and if there are follow-up questions I will follow up.